# How could an array be undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm looping through a database query

```
(async () =>{
    let client;
    try {
        client = await MongoClient;
        let collection = client.db("booliscraper").collection("sold");
        let docs = await collection.find();
        await docs.forEach((sale) => {
            console.log(sale.location.namedAreas, typeof sale.location.namedAreas);
            sale.street = sale.location.namedAreas[0]
        });
    client.close(); 

  } catch(err) {
    log(err)
  }
})()
```

I get outputs like this, 100's of them:

```
[ 'Kungsholmen' ] 'object'
[ 'Blåsut' ] 'object'
[ 'Östermalm' ] 'object'
[ 'Beckomberga Bromma' ] 'object'
[ 'Södermalm' ] 'object'
[ 'Johanneshov' ] 'object'
[ 'Vasastan' ] 'object'
[ 'Hässelby-Vällingby' ] 'object'
[ 'Vasastan' ] 'object'
[ 'Östermalm' ] 'object'
[ 'Norra Djurgårdsstaden' ] 'object'
[ 'Gröndal' ] 'object'
[ 'Norrmalm' ] 'object'
[ 'Minneberg' ] 'object'
[ 'Bromma Brommaplan' ] 'object'
[ 'Älvsjö' ] 'object'
[ 'Vasastan' ] 'object'
```

suddenly, after that last one, it throws an error:

/Users/kristoffernolgren/web/booliscrape/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:206
      throw err;
      ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at docs.forEach (/Users/kristoffernolgren/web/booliscrape/updaterecords.js:15:42)
```

that is this line:

```
            sale.street = sale.location.namedAreas[0]
```

Why doesn't ['Vasatstan'] have a property [0]

docs have 40000 items in it. Here is an example however:

```
{ _id: 5beca43b78f21248ab47f835,
  location:
   { address: { streetAddress: 'Sankt Eriksgatan 22' },
     position: { latitude: 59.3315552, longitude: 18.03116681 },
     namedAreas: [ 'Kungsholmen', [length]: 1 ],
     region:
      { municipalityName: 'Stockholm', countyName: 'Stockholms län' },
     distance: { ocean: 2252 } },
  listPrice: 5395000,
  rent: 1517,
  floor: 2,
  livingArea: 73,
  additionalArea: 0,
  source:
   { name: 'Bjurfors',
     id: 1561,
     type: 'Broker',
     url: 'http://www.bjurfors.se/' },
  rooms: 3,
  published: 2018-08-09T12:21:49.000Z,
  constructionYear: 1984,
  objectType: 'Lägenhet',
  booliId: 3195821,
  soldDate: 2018-10-27T00:00:00.000Z,
  soldPrice: 5430000,
  apartmentNumber: '1204',
  soldPriceSource: 'bid',
  publishedDays: 708,
  soldDays: 786,
  daysUp: 78,
  street: 'Kungsholmen',
  streetYear: 'Kungsholmen 1984',
  yearDay: 'something' 
}
```

Here is the once that makes it break:

```
{ _id: 5beca4cf78f21248ab48087b,
  location:
   { address: { streetAddress: 'Sankt Eriksgatan 71' },
     position: { latitude: 59.3385408, longitude: 18.03577423 },
     namedAreas: [ 'Vasastan', [length]: 1 ],
     region:
      { municipalityName: 'Stockholm', countyName: 'Stockholms län' },
     distance: { ocean: 2230 } },
  listPrice: 4795000,
  rent: 2462,
  floor: 4,
  livingArea: 54,
  additionalArea: 0,
  source:
   { name: 'Bjurfors',
     id: 1561,
     type: 'Broker',
     url: 'http://www.bjurfors.se/' },
  rooms: 2,
  published: 2018-08-10T10:15:06.000Z,
  constructionYear: 1929,
  objectType: 'Lägenhet',
  booliId: 3188830,
  soldDate: 2018-08-23T00:00:00.000Z,
  soldPrice: 5270000,
  soldPriceSource: 'bid',
  url: 'https://www.booli.se/annons/3188830' 
}
```

Comment: can you post how's your `docs` look like ?

Comment: *"Why doesn't ['Vasatstan'] have a property [0]"* That's not what the error is telling you. The error is tellling you that `sale.location.namedAreas` is `undefined`, not that it's something without a `0` property.

Comment: My guess would be that the error is coming from a **separate** call to `docs.forEach`, not the one logging `[ 'Vasastan' ] 'object'`, but really the only way to figure this out will be by using your debugger.

Comment: (For those who, like I, didn't realize it: The `forEach` above is [this MongoClient method](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach), not `Array#forEach`, and does indeed return a promise.)

Comment: It probably doesn't output the elements in order. You have a 100 of them as you said. Look through all of them and see if there one that gives a weird output.

Comment: @codeManiac, Updated @TjCrowder, yes, but `console.log(sale.location.namedAreas)` outputs ['Vasastan'] in the loop that breaks. @kemicofa, interesting, how can I do that? Put a 100ms delay in each loop?